# How to use XML for an RPG Stat/Leveling system

Tags: c#, xml, monogame

I'm looking at developing an RPG engine mostly for development experience, not really aiming for anything commercial. I've hit a bit of a wall, however, when it comes to storing Class base stats. I've worked more extensively in Game Maker for a number of years, so my experience is more geared toward that. I'm currently working in C# with Monogame and wrapping my head around it.

I believe a good method of storing the information I need will require external files, from what I have read. I am used to calling and using INI files from GM, but have not had as much being able to wrap my head around XML. I have a public pastebin of the setup I'm hoping to achieve, and was curious on your guys' take if such a setup is viable or if I'm trying to do this in some awful fashion.

The XML document I was designing (entirely by theory) is structured like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<BaseClass>
  <Class Class="Barbarian">
    <Level Level="1">
      <baseAtk>1</baseAtk>
      <baseFort>2</baseFort>
      <baseRef>0</baseRef>
      <baseWill>0</baseWill>
      <classSkillCt>2</classSkillCt>
      <classSkill0>ID_CS_BARB_FASTMOVE</classSkill0>
      <classSkill1>ID_CS_BARB_RAGE</classSkill1>
    </Level>
    <Level Level="2">
      <baseAtk>2</baseAtk>
      <baseFort>3</baseFort>
      <baseRef>0</baseRef>
      <baseWill>0</baseWill>
      <classSkillCt>2</classSkillCt>
      <classSkill0>ID_CS_BARB_UNCDODGE</classSkill0>
      <classSkill1>ID_CS_BARB_RAGEPWR1</classSkill1>
    </Level>
    <Level Level="3">
      <baseAtk>3</baseAtk>
      <baseFort>3</baseFort>
      <baseRef>1</baseRef>
      <baseWill>1</baseWill>
      <classSkillCt>1</classSkillCt>
      <classSkill0>ID_CS_BARB_TRAPSENSE1</classSkill0>
    </Level>
    <Level Level="4">
      <baseAtk>4</baseAtk>
      <baseFort>4</baseFort>
      <baseRef>1</baseRef>
      <baseWill>1</baseWill>
      <classSkillCt>1</classSkillCt>
      <classSkill0>ID_CS_BARB_RAGEPWR2</classSkill0>
    </Level>
    <Level Level="5">
      <baseAtk>5</baseAtk>
      <baseFort>4</baseFort>
      <baseRef>1</baseRef>
      <baseWill>1</baseWill>
      <classSkillCt>1</classSkillCt>
      <classSkill0>ID_CS_BARB_IMPUNCDODGE</classSkill0>
    </Level>
  </Class>
  <Class Class="Bard">
    <Level Level="1">
      <baseAtk>2</baseAtk>
      <baseFort>1</baseFort>
      <baseRef>3</baseRef>
      <baseWill>3</baseWill>
      <spellDay0>4</spellDay0>
      <spellDay1>1</spellDay1>
      <spellDay2>0</spellDay2>
      <spellDay3>0</spellDay3>
      <spellDay4>0</spellDay4>
      <spellDay5>0</spellDay5>
      <spellDay6>0</spellDay6>
      <spellDay7>0</spellDay7>
      <spellDay8>0</spellDay8>
      <spellDay9>0</spellDay9>
      <spellKnw0>6</spellKnw0>
      <spellKnw1>4</spellKnw1>
      <spellKnw2>0</spellKnw2>
      <spellKnw3>0</spellKnw3>
      <spellKnw4>0</spellKnw4>
      <spellKnw5>0</spellKnw5>
      <spellKnw6>0</spellKnw6>
      <spellKnw7>0</spellKnw7>
      <spellKnw8>0</spellKnw8>
      <spellKnw9>0</spellKnw9>
      <classSkillCt>6</classSkillCt>
      <classSkill0>ID_CL_SKILL_BRD_BRDKNOWLEDGE</classSkill0>
      <classSkill1>ID_CL_SKILL_BRD_BRDPERFORM</classSkill1>
      <classSkill2>ID_CL_SKILL_BRD_COUNTERSONG</classSkill2>
      <classSkill3>ID_CL_SKILL_BRD_DISTRACTION</classSkill3>
      <classSkill4>ID_CL_SKILL_BRD_FASCINATE</classSkill4>
      <classSkill5>ID_CL_SKILL_BRD_INSPCOURAGE1</classSkill5>
    </Level>
  </Class>
</BaseClass>
```

If this is not how XML documents work, please let me know so I'm not screwing the pooch on this one! I'm not looking for anyone to write the code for me, just for open suggestions on what would be the best way to achieve what I'm looking for. I'd like to be able to somehow get the base stats of any class at any level I request. So if I were to request (Barbarian,2) or something of that nature, I'd get the information for a level 2 barbarian :)

I've tried to follow a number of tutorials online, but have not yet found one that has really explained the best way to utilize any external files in a way that makes sense. If anyone has suggested materials on this kind of information, please let me know!

Comment: The XML doc you've got is fine, although I'd probably use attributes for `baseAtk`, `baseFort` etc. It's not really clear what you're asking for though - questions requesting off-site tutorials etc are off-topic, and you haven't given us a specific problem to help you solve. If you can use LINQ to XML, I'd *strongly* recommend that as a nice XML API. Beyond that, please make your question more specific.

Comment: I would not use tag names with number at the end.  I would make the number an attribute like id which makes the xml easier to parse.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond!

@JonSkeet Sorry the question is so open-ended. I more or less don't have a strong grasp on how XML works and am attempting to learn a method to store and pull data regarding X Class at Y Level, so I don't have to hard-code all this information into a class :) Because I don't yet have a good grasp on how to parse any of the information out of an XML document, I wanted to make sure my little understanding of it was correct so I knew i wasn't going nowhere.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the input! I would not have thought of that and would definitely look better!

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is fine, though maybe the BaseClass element should be plural and should agree with its content elements ("Classes") which are just Class.

For extracting, for instance, the base attack bonus for a level 2 barbarian you would use an XPath expression of the form "./BaseClass/Class[@Class='Barbarian']/Level[@Level='2']/baseAtk".  Alternately, you would use LINQ.

Comment: Awesome! I'll definitely look into all of that :) Your input is much appreciated!

Comment: While XPath is certainly one option, I'd personally use LINQ to XML to avoid effectively embedding one language within another - `root.Element("BaseClass").Elements("Class").Where(...)` etc. Matter of personal taste though.

Comment: @JonSkeet - first, I haven't spoken with you since the daily wtf a decade ago!  And second, I concluded that since the question is obviously someone learning XML, that they could use a brush up on XPath as well ;)  Good to see you man!